# Need help to click on a button in ghost inspector

Tags: javascript, click, ghost-inspector

I tried all the below options :

1) maximize the screen and click on the button - didnt work

```
top.window.moveTo(0,0);
if (document.all) {
top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
}
else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) {
if (top.window.outerHeight<screen.availHeight||top.window.outerWidth<screen.availWidth){
top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
}
}
```

2) click via x,y coordinates - didnt work

I entered the folleoing code to Ghost Inspector page:
`document.elementFromPoint(92, 309).click();`

Please help me to understand my issue here.

Comment: Wouldn't you just: `document.getElementById('button-id').click();`? It's been a while since I've used ghostinspector and I was using jQuery for dom-manipulation instead of plain js.

Comment: The code is as follows <a class="btn btn-outline incred button-next" href="javascript:;">Continue <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>' .I do not have an option for id here . I was using driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href="javascript:;" and @class="btn btn-outline incred button-next"])).click initially. I tried for other options when this does not work

Comment: @Sapna if you are still having issues with this, please reach out to support and we will help you come up with a solution: https://ghostinspector.com/support/